# HKErrorDomain (HealthKit Error Domain) Constant in Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, healthkit, nserror

I am writing some error handling for when my HealthKit client requests permission to data in Xamarin iOS.  I make the request like so:

```
public HKClient()
{
    var HealthKitStore = new HKHealthStore();
    HealthKitStore.RequestAuthorizationToShare (dataTypesToWrite, dataTypesToRead, OnHealthPermissionsCompleted);
}

void OnHealthPermissionsCompleted (bool success, NSError error)
{
    //Parse error.Domain and error.Code herere
}
```

In my OnHealthPermissionsCompleted, I want to parse the NSError in order to debug why our request failed.  The first thing to do is check error.Domain to make sure it is a HealthKit error and then compare error.Code to the constants in the HKErrorCode enum.  The problem is, I cannot find any constant for what should be in error.Domain for HealthKit related errors.  The Apple documentation says there should be a constant called "HKErrorDomain" for me to compare to, however it is not there in Xamarin.
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HealthKit_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Health_Kit_Error_Domain

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/HealthKit/

If I force an error and then check it in the debugger, I do see that error.Domain = "com.apple.healthkit".  I could just compare to that string,

```
void OnHealthPermissionsCompleted (bool success, NSError error)
{
    if(!success && error.Domain == "com.apple.healthkit")
    { 
        //continue parsing...
    }
}
```

but putting magic strings in these kinds of things makes me feel icky, especially when I know a constant for this exists in native iOS.  Am I missing something here or is this my only option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now a bug filed on Xamarin's Bugzilla to surface this constant:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=34140